# I need a little help to optimize

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to optimize this query, but only using index, hints, clusters and pctfree and pctused. Thanks.

```
WITH
     A AS (SELECT SSN from contracts where (end_date is null or end_date>sysdate)),
     B AS (SELECT SSN,start_date, NVL(end_date,sysdate) finish,
         (NVL(end_date,sysdate)-start_date) length
     FROM CONTRACTS NATURAL JOIN A)
     SELECT SSN
        FROM B
        GROUP BY SSN HAVING (Max(finish)-MIN(start_date)) > SUM(length)
```

Comment: It's quite impossible to optimize a query without knowing your complete table structure ( with at least columns and indexes) and the explain plan of the actual statement, please post. Can you create new indexes or only use existing ones? Why clusters, pctfree and pctused? Are your tables already existing, or you need to create new tables, so that they will be easy to access with your query? Please be careful with NATURAL JOIN, it can be very dangerous.

Comment: Why do you even need the join at all? You could just put the where clause from your A subquery into your B subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get rid of the join by using an analytic query:

```
SELECT SSN
FROM   (
  SELECT SSN,
         start_date,
         NVL( end_date, SYSDATE ) finish,
         COUNT( CASE WHEN end_date IS NULL OR end_date > SYSDATE THEN 1 END )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY SSN ) AS has_invalid_end_date,
  FROM   contracts
)
WHERE  has_invalid_end_date > 0
GROUP BY SSN
HAVING   MAX( finish ) - MIN( start_date ) > SUM( finish - start_date );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just rewrite this as:

```
with b as (select ssn,
                  start_date,
                  nvl(end_date, sysdate) finish_date,
                  nvl(end_date, sysdate) - start_date duration
           from   contracts)
select   ssn
from     b
where    end_date is null
or       end_date > sysdate
group by ssn
having   max(finish_date) - min(start_date) > sum(duration);
```

You might also benefit from having an index on (ssn, start_date, end_date).